Nativescript obtaining Another (upper) View from Button of Inner Frame
Recently I used the drawerapp template using the usual instruction as mentioned here.
I have no problem for acquirement this until the deployment. Then, I add a new page for login:

And make some adjustment inside the app-root.xml as the following:

with extra portion layout that I want to be visible or hidden partially.

And then, inside the login-page.xml I have this portion that makes the button calling function onVerify.

When I made some adjustment inside login-page.js especially for onVerify function:
 export function onVerify(args){
  var page = args.object.page;
  var form = getViewById(page, "login-form-layout");
  page.frame.navigate({
    moduleName: 'home/home-page',
    clearHistory: true,
  });

  // but the code below didnt work!
  var menuUnlogged = page.getViewById("unlogged");
  var menuLogged = page.getViewById("logged-in");

  menuUnlogged.visibility = "collapse";
  menuLogged.visibility = "visible";
}

So when the button is tapped (clicked), it should make the Grid view become hidden and the other GridView become visible. But on the fact, it didn't work that way. The app crashed!
The error I obtained, is telling me there is undefined variable.

TypeError : cannot set properties of undefined (setting visibility).

Is that the referencing variable that didn't catch the view element or something else I didn't understand yet?
